# Extracting multiple object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

I have an object like this:

```
object["key1"] = "text1"
object["key2"] = "text2"
object["key3"] = "text1"
object["key4"] = "text3"
```

How can I give out (e.g. alert) the elements with the same values (text1, text2 and so on)?

In the above example it should be `object["key1"]` and `object["key2"]`.

Thanks

Comment: Um...loop through the array and test each value?

Comment: That's not an array, that's an object. Arrays in JavaScript only have numerical keys.

Comment: I assume you mean `object['key1']` and `object['key3']`?

Answer (score 4):

You could "invert" your object (properties become values, values become properties):

```
var byValue = {};

for (var prop in object) {
    if (!(object[prop] in byValue)) {
        byValue[object[prop]] = [];
    }
    byValue[object[prop]].push(prop);
}
```

This should yield this structure:

```
{
    'text1': ['key1', 'key3'],
    'text2': ['key2'],
    'text3': ['key4']
}
```

Then, you can detect those values that had duplicate keys:

```
for (var value in byValue) {
    if (byValue[value].length > 1) {
        alert(byValue[value].join(', '));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my script

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/LAnRt/

This does not check for identity in complex values, just for equality (see foo example)

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted the array and then considered that you would want to alert,or do any 
functionality, only once for every repeated element. 
WARNING: Sorting can get heavy with the size of the array
http://jsfiddle.net/SPQJ7/
The above fiddle is already setup and working with multiple reapeated elements